# Extracting values from columns in tab delim text file

Tags: regex, r, split, extract

perlI have tab delimited text file with 3 columns like following

```
Name                Description                         Ontology
dda1        box1_homodomain gn=box1 os=homo   C:Cell;C:surface;F:binding;P:toy
dda2        sox2_plurinet gn=plu os=mouse     C:Organ;F:transport;P:carrier;P:avi
dd13        klf4_iPSC gn=klf os=Bos           C:Cell;F:tiad;P:abs;P:digestion
```

Now I would like to split the  values (gn=xxx and os=xxx) in column Description and values in Ontology column(C:xxx;F=xxx;P=xxx;) into seperate columns like following:

```
Name   Description     gn      os        C              F              P       
dda1  box1_homodomain box1    homo    Cell;surface    binding          toy
dda2  sox2_plurinet   plu     mouse   Organ;          transport    carrier;avi
dd13  klf4_iPSC       klf     Bos     Cell;            tiad       abs;digestion
```

I want this has to export as tab delim file or excel file.I would be really great if someone can guide how can I achieve that in perl. Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question would be better if you'd asked only about a single language. Permitting answers in multiple languages is just going to reduce the usefulness to future readers seeking an answer in the language they are currently writing in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw perl question after 5 years of my Java. I was excited and i want to do this exercise. Now, that i remember things i did and pasted the code below. Just enrich the same code for last column 'Ontology' with regexp and same hash concept you are done. You can do multiple ways in perl. It could be more code. But, i remember below way.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Data::Dumper;
my %output;
open(IN, "stack.txt");
while(<IN>) {
  my @nameColumns, @descriptionColumns;
  if ($_ =~ /Name/) {
    $ouput{'Name'} = @nameColumns;
    $ouput{'Description'} = @descriptionColumns;
    next;
  }
  my ($group1, $group2, $group3, $group4, $group5, $group6, $group7) = ($_ =~ m/(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\=(\w+)\s+(\w+)\=(\w+)\s+(.*)/gi);
  # Column 1
  @nameColumns = @{$output{'Name'}};
  push(@nameColumns, $group1);
  $output{'Name'} = [@nameColumns];

  # Column 2
  #print "$group2, $group3, $group4, $group5, $group6, $group7"; 
  @descriptionColumns = @{$output{'Description'}};
  push(@descriptionColumns, $group2);
  $output{'Description'} = [@descriptionColumns];

  # column 3
  @column3 = @{$output{$group3}};
  push(@column3, $group4);
  $output{$group3} = [@column3];

  # column 4
  @column4 = @{$output{$group5}};
  push(@column4, $group6);
  $output{$group5} = [@column4];

  #Column ...

}
close(IN);
print Dumper(\%output);
```

```html
$VAR1 = {
          'gn' => [
                    'box1',
                    'plu',
                    'klf'
                  ],
          'os' => [
                    'homo',
                    'mouse',
                    'Bos'
                  ],
          'Name' => [
                      'dda1',
                      'dda2',
                      'dd13'
                    ],
          'Description' => [
                             'box1_homodomain',
                             'sox2_plurinet',
                             'klf4_iPSC'
                           ]
        };
```

**Note : Output above. If you still didn't figure out, how to finish this program let me know to spend more time**